# Jquery: Stripping certain Wordpress paragraphs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tags, parent

Since Wordpress adds paragraph tags on everything, I need to strip paragraph tags under certain conditions.  In this case, I want them off the images.  I got that part working:

```
    $(".scroller img").unwrap();
```

But I think that Wordpress might not add paragraph tags around images forever, so then my code would break, and it would strip the parent instead, which I don't want.

How can I make a check on this, that says "if parent tag is p on the image, then strip it"?

Or how to tell Wordpress not to wrap paragraph tags around solo images would be ok too. :)

Thanks!

Comment: IF you wrap your image tags in a `div` WordPress won't wrap them in a paragraph tag.

Comment: Yes I think you're right about that, but it did when I had 12 images in the div.  Might be a little finicky, which is why I wanted the extra check there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".scroller p>img").unwrap();
```

This will select and unwrap only img tags with p parents(inside of .scroller)

Answer (score 0):

use this as the test for every image

```
 image.parent().get(0).tagName​​​​​ == "P"
```

It gets the parent block, gets the first element in the block and checks whether its tagname is P

Good luck!

Comment: Didn't understand about .tagName; couldn't find it by searching in jquery site.  Do you have a super secret list?  :)

Comment: Thanks for admission to the secret club, Musa!